# How to hide a div until a certain date

Tags: c#, html, date

I have a div that I need to hide until October 12, then have it display starting October 13.  The site is being built in C# .NET so I can add an if statement to the code-behind of the HTML page.  Not sure if this is possible or if I will need a jQuery solution (which I know nothing about).  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code in the HTML:

```
<p style="bold">SHOW THROUGH 10/12!!!<p>
<p>Every day from now until Metastatic Breast Cancer Awareness Day (Oct. 13), a new video will be featured. Please check-in every day to hear a new story and come back on Oct. 13 to see the new, complete video wall.</p>

<div id="mbcRadioList">
    <p style="bold">BUILD BUT HIDE UNTIL 10/13!!!<p>
    <p><strong>Want to learn more?</strong> Select a video topic to better understand the varied experiences of people living with MBC and their family and friends.</p>
    <div class="checkBoxesColumn">
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />View All</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" checked />My MBC Journey</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />Challenges</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />Positive Outlooks &amp; Advice</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />Giving Thanks</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />Family / Friend Perspective</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added the the `<div id="mbcRadioList">` around the list to get a handle to control in the code-behind if there is a way to do this.  I can remove it if it is a jQuery solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what I'd try is mark the div as hidden, and then check  in your page load event whether or not it should be unhidden

Comment: If you put an id and a `runat="server"` on the element you can reference it in your code-behind and set Visible to false based on your condition.

Comment: I would not advice this to be a client side thing. Because the user can change his system date to any date in the future

Comment: I can do it server side, I just don't remember the correct way to set specific dates.

Comment: Don't forget to take time zones into consideration.  Should the hidden div appear for all users, regardless of location, at the same time (midnight at some arbitrary location)?  Or should it appear at midnight of each user's local time?

Comment: Another danger of making this a client-side issue:  TIMEZONES.  You'd have to do all your math on GMT time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as the other's have suggested:

1) Set the div to `runat="server"`

2) Set the div to `visible="false"`

3) In `Page_Load`, in your codebehind, add an `if` statement which checks the date and then changes `visible` to `true`

aspx markup:

```
<div id="mbcRadioList" runat="server" visible="false">
    <p style="bold">BUILD BUT HIDE UNTIL 10/13!!!<p>
    <p><strong>Want to learn more?</strong> Select a video topic to better understand the varied experiences of people living with MBC and their family and friends.</p>
    <div class="checkBoxesColumn">
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />View All</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" checked />My MBC Journey</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />Challenges</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />Positive Outlooks &amp; Advice</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />Giving Thanks</label>
        <label><input name="videoWallRadio" type="radio" id="" value="" />Family / Friend Perspective</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ..... your other code

                    if(DateTime.Now >= new DateTime(2012, 10, 13) ){
                          mbcRadioList.Visible = true;
                    }
    }
```

As the other guys have suggested, make sure you take into consideration timezones, if required.